# How to define at least one occurrence of a string between two tokens in bottom up LALR(1) parser grammar

Tags: formal-grammars, parsing

I am trying to define a non terminal symbol in a LALR(1) grammar (with CUP parser). It is requested that

```
the <code> token must appear exactly twice, 
while the <hour> token must appear at least once.
```

In the end I came up with this definition:

```
section     ::= hour_l CODE SC hour_l CODE SC hour_l ;
hour_l      ::= /* epsilon */ 
            | hour_l HOUR SC ;
```

where `SC` is a separator (semicolon) between tokens and `hour_l` is the non terminal symbol for hour's list.
This solution has a problem: `HOUR` can be absent, because `epsilon` can be reduced from `hour_l`.
Is there a clever solution other than specifying all possibilities or using the semantic capabilities of CUP (ie. putting a counter of how many times `HOUR` is present in `section`)? I'd prefer not to use semantics in order to achieve this; in fact, it seems to me this is syntax related.

Thanks

Comment: if it's _at least one_, you must replace $\epsilon$ by the canonical element (here `HOUR`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution, suggested by a friend, is to use a Finite State Machine. I drew a Deterministic Finite Automata, and $C$ is the final state accepted by this machine:

[image: DFA]

I then transformed it into a right regular grammar:

```
section     ::= c ;
a           ::= CODE SC ;
b           ::= a CODE SC ;
c           ::= c HOUR SC | b HOUR SC | e CODE SC ;
d           ::= HOUR SC | d HOUR SC ;
e           ::= e HOUR SC | a HOUR SC | d CODE SC ;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: very interesting!